# display 0 before number data type during create table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I basically have a table called as person as below

```
    create table Person
    (
       Name varchar2 (50),
       Phone_number Number (15)
    );
```

the problem i faced is not sure in how to make 0 appear infront of it when i insert values to it.

```
     insert into person values ('James', 0162323456);
```

is there any ways i can solve this

Comment: Make Phone_number data type as varchar(15)

Comment: In addition to your current problem, the numeric datatype might prevent you from dealing with phone extensions.

Comment: so there is no ways except making it varchar

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to force Oracle to retain the leading zeroes when loading into a number type because Oracle (and every RDBMS that I know of) only keeps track of [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).  This means that leading and trailing zeros will be removed.

I would recommend that when you read the number from the table to convert it using [`TO_CHAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm) and giving it the appropriate length.  For example, `TO_CHAR(123, '09999') = '00123'`.

If that's not acceptable, you'll need to change your column type from a numeric format to a string format, possibly VARCHAR2.